# RAILS Time Zone - Show time based on web user's locaton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have developed online examination system, and while creating exam i submit "exam start time", this is stored in the database as UTC,

for example say exam start time "Sun Jan 29 15:30:00 UTC 2012",

Student from India should see the exam start time in his local time i.e "Sun Jan 29 21:00:00 +0530 2012"

Student from France should see the exam start time in his local time,

please guide me how i can acheive this,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267170/how-to-display-the-time-in-users-timezone) on Stackoverflow I used the information from [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13/how-can-i-determine-a-web-users-time-zone) to resolve this one:

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;
```

It is a javascript function but can easily be put in application.html.erb or elsewhere if you want a less obtrusive form.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know where the student is from, you can use:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html#method-i-in_time_zone

Otherwise, go with Scott's suggestion.