# In ruby on rails, how to display the time correctly in the client?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http

I have a `ruby-on-rails` server that implements a `JSON` `REST` API e.g.

`http://my-server.com/end_of_promotion.json`

Currently, the answer is:

```
{
    date: "2013-03-31T14:29:16Z"
}
```

In my `model`, date is an attribute of type: `datetime`.

Now, I would like the client to display this date in the user timezone.
How should I design the API and the client code to make it happen?

Comment: is your app aware of where the user is? Can you include the controller/model code that generates that time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267170/how-to-display-the-time-in-users-timezone

Comment: Maybe you should use timestamp?

Comment: You could output a unix timestamp or an RFC 2822 compliant date, then pass it to the javascript Date object, which considers the client time settings.

Comment: @viebel - Please mark the answer if it was helpful for you! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more detail on your situation, here are some helpful resources.

For time zones on Rails, have a look here for the various options you can use: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

To format for your users, look into strftime. Docs: http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime

A site that helps you generate strftime code: http://strftime.net/

A guide to I18n / internationalization: guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html (thanks @house9)