# how can i convert utc time to local time timezone with +05:30

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to convert UTC time to user local time. For local time zone if have values like:

```
user_id   time_zone
 23       +05:30
 25       +10:00
```

is this sufficient info? How can i convert using this. In documentation all i could find is this method.

```
Time.now.in_time_zone('Eastern Time (US & Canada)')
```

but i dont have that. Or should I fetch this `Eastern Time (US & Canada)` using +10:00

I am trying to trigger push notifications at 10 am of user's time.

Comment: pls look into gem "browser-timezone-rails" which helps to convert and save local time in UTC and vice-versa.

Comment: @chaitanya Using gems for this kind of problem is `leftpad syndrome`, which is in turn a decease.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267170/how-to-display-the-time-in-users-timezone

Comment: @GokulM what value this answer adds to what OP already has?

Comment: @mudasobwa It tells how to get the time in user timezone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%w|+05:30 +10:00|.map do |time_zone|
  hours, mins = time_zone.split(':').map(&:to_i).map(&:abs)
  sign = time_zone[0] == '-' ? -1 : 1
  Time.now.in_time_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone[(hours + 1.0 * mins / 60]) * sign)
end
#⇒ [Wed, 06 Jul 2016 12:54:10 IST +05:30, Wed, 06 Jul 2016 17:24:10 AEST +10:00]
```

Comment: NB: in the previous implementation there was a bug: it failed on '-0:30' timezone. AFAIK, such a timezone does not exist, but anyway I corrected a solution.